# Problems with installing appropriate gtk library

Tags: gedit

I'm trying to install latest release of Gedit. It's my favourite editor for coding. And I'm following this guide: https://installfights.blogspot.co.uk/2016/08/install-lastest-gedit-version-3202-on.html

However, when I get to the point where I need to install gtk library version 3.22.x I can't seem to find it freely available online.
I'm not allowed to proceed in installation because of this error:

```
Requested 'gtk+-3.0 >= 3.22.0' but version of GTK+ is 3.18.9
```

So I'm currently running 3.18 and I need 3.22 but where to download it ?

Comment: Did you try https://www.gtk.org/download/linux.php ?

Comment: You Google better than I do. Nice one ! If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest source code of should be available at [Gtk+: Download for GNU/Linux and Unix](https://www.gtk.org/download/linux.php). Older point releases are available from this page as well.

You will of course need to build the libraries yourself from this source - there is a [PPA of version 3.22.28 backported from Artful](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/gtk3.22) but I can't vouch for it.